Is aria-labelledby necessary when there is "for" and "id" association with label and input?
Below is the html structure for Text Field component from Adobe Spectrum: https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-spectrum/TextField.html
There is for attribute on <label> and id on <input> which gets screen reader to read out the label when input is focused. So why is aria-labelledby here is necessary? As per their document, it states
"If a visible label isn't specified, an aria-label must be provided to the TextField for accessibility. If the field is labeled by a separate element, an aria-labelledby prop must be provided using the id of the labeling element instead."
But isn't for and id association enough?
<div class="A-HlBa_spectrum-Field A-HlBa_spectrum-Field--positionTop YO3Nla_spectrum-Textfield-wrapper">
  <label id="react-aria3159902326-:r2i:" class="A-HlBa_spectrum-FieldLabel" for="react-aria3159902326-:r2h:">Name</label>
  <div class="YO3Nla_spectrum-Textfield YO3Nla_spectrum-FocusRing YO3Nla_spectrum-FocusRing-ring A-HlBa_spectrum-Field-field">
    <input type="text" id="react-aria3159902326-:r2h:" aria-labelledby="react-aria3159902326-:r2i:" class="YO3Nla_spectrum-Textfield-input YO3Nla_i18nFontFamily" value="">
  </div>
</div>


You are correct. There is no need for aria-label and aria-labelledby when the field has already its associated label.
As per ARIA rules,

you shouldn't use ARIA unless you really need to;
you shouldn't override with ARIA what's already implicit or given by another mean.

Here, the aria-labelledby is clearly redundant, so should be removed.
In fact, being redundant can be detrimental. An element with or without ARIA can sometimes behave slightly differently, and is a call for bugs or unwanted result in accessible name calculation.
Normally, ARIA takes precedence, but this is only the standard. Screen readers don't always respect fully the standard.
Their doc state that aria-label or aria-labelledby is needed when there is no visible label.
This is also more or less what WCAG says.
By visible, here, you must understand visible by the screen reader, not necessarily visible on screen.
As per their own doc, they shouldn't have included that aria-labelledby here.
If the code has been machine generated, they should improve their algorithm  in order to include aria-label / aria-labelledby only when really necessary.
